# C# How does the method OrderBy sorts objects by chars containing husky codes?

Tags: c#, linq, sorting, char, sql-order-by

C# How does the method OrderBy sorts objects by char that are not letters??
To clarify and specify, I have the object Card and it has a property of Suit which can return the following chars:
♦
♣
♥
♠

So what happens? How does the function know how to sort?

Comment: By their Unicode representatives.

Answer (score 2):

The answer to your question depends upon whether you are using **LINQ to SQL** or **LINQ to Objects**.

LINQ sorting is not necessarily a .NET sorting. It's making SQL to sort the data including the special characters on SQL server if you use LINQ to SQL.

Ordering charcters in SQL, follows an alphabetical order unless you explicitly specify an ASCII Order as mentioned below

```
SELECT * FROM .... ORDER BY ASCII(....)
```

Normal `ORDER BY` in SQL follows the alphabetical ordering approach

- NULLs are the lowest value
- followed by special characters
- followed by numbers
- and then letters

On contrary LINQ to Object Sorting follows the .NET sorting which is based on Unicodes utilizing the current culture for sorting.

if we consider these characters ♠ ♥ ♦ ♣ { 1

Linq to SQL will order them as : `{ ♠ ♣ ♥ ♦ 1` based on the above mentioned ordering

Linq to Object will order it as : `1 { ♠ ♣ ♥ ♦` based on Unicodes.